# mdf2iso doesn't recognize *.mdf file

Tags: 14.04, iso, cd-image, format-conversion

Mounting an MDF disc image file outputs: "convert to *.iso format", so I use mdf2iso which gives:

```
$ mdf2iso obraz.mdf

mdf2iso v0.3.1 by Salvatore Santagati
Licensed under GPL v2 or later
Unknown format for obraz.mdf
```

I haven't found any solution to that problem, although other users had this same bug. Any piece of advice?

Answer (score 6):

`mdf2iso` doesn't seem to support all MDF files, notably those created by Alcohol 120% which contain lots of extra anti-anti-piracy metadata.

Use `iat` instead, it works in more cases (although still not all), and succeeds `mdf2iso`.